# I'm having a warning with stringWithContentsOfFile, parameter usedEncoding?

Tags: objective-c, ios, utf-8, nsstring

I simply tried this :

```
NSString *docPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Docs/data.txt"];
NSString *dataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docPath usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Using this, I'm having this warning :

> Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSStringEncoding *' (aka 'unsigned int *');

What is wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Instead of

```
NSString *dataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docPath usedEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
```

Use

```
NSString *dataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docPath 
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding 
                                                  error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use

```
NSStringEncoding *encoding = nil;
NSString *dataFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:docPath usedEncoding:encoding error:nil];
```

But Omar is right.. replace "usedEncoding" with "encoding" and you are good to go.